# Why is Angular component property undefined after http.get

Tags: angular

**Why is "this.Trails" *undefined* in the constructor after *http.get*?**

The *http.get* is succesfull, but "*this.Trails*" is *undefined* all the way. Still, in my page I am able to output the items. I don't understant this.

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'salvamont',
    templateUrl: './salvamont.component.html'
})
export class SalvamontComponent {
    public Trails: HikingTrail[];
    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/HikingTrails')
          .subscribe(result => { 
            this.Trails = result.json();
          }, 
          error => console.error(error));

        if (this.Trails != undefined) {
            console.log("has items");
        }        
    }    
}

class HikingTrail {
   //some members
    }
```

Comment: after .subscribe(result... what is raw result? Or do you catch it in error? You have also confirmed that your request does return something in the browser network tab?

Comment: at which stage exactly are you checking that it is undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Http.get() is an async call which will get processed on next tick (after it is resolved or rejected)

```
if (this.Trails != undefined) {
   console.log("has items");
}
```

The above code is executed before the subscription

```
this.Trails = result.json();
```

Thus undefiend

Comment: ok, I understand. All http.get calls are async in Angular. Thank you